# How can I comprehend this sentence "two instances with the same hash value don’t necessarily compare equally. "

Tags: swift, hashable, equatable

When I reading the book Advanced Swift and in the Chapter 'Hashable Requirement', I got confused by this explanation

> two instances that are equal (as defined by your == implementation) must have the same hash value. The reverse isn’t true: two instances with the same hash value don’t necessarily compare equally.

How can I comprehend the 'reverse' situation, or why do the two instances with the same hash value don’t necessarily compare equally.

Comment: Example: there are infinitely many strings, but only 2^64 possible hash values ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the hash value as a *quick*, *compact*, *non-unique* identifier for a given object instance. The only hard condition is this: if two objects compare equally, according to the `==` operator, than both instances *must* have the exact same hash value. That’s all there is to it ;)

In particular, given that hash values aren’t unique — and how they could be given `Int` limited range? — we *can’t* safely assume that two instances with the same hash value will compare equally.